# Missing NVIDIA scripts and C files after kernel 5.8.0-45 update

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, kernel, ubuntu-20.04

I have just upgraded to Kernel version 5.8.0-45 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. However, this seems to have broken the NVIDIA drivers. I have isolated the problem to the `linux-image-nvidia-5.8.0-45-generic` package. This is what the apt logs say:

```
linux-image-nvidia-5.8.0-45-generic: constructing .ko files
./BUILD: 1: scripts/genksyms/genksyms: not found
cc: error: nvidia/nv-frontend.c: No such file or directory
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
./BUILD: 10: scripts/genksyms/genksyms: not found
cc: error: nvidia/nv-p2p.c: No such file or directory
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
./BUILD: 22: scripts/genksyms/genksyms: not found
cc: error: nvidia/nv-modeset-interface.c: No such file or directory
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
./BUILD: 25: scripts/genksyms/genksyms: not found
cc: error: nvidia/nv-report-err.c: No such file or directory
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
./BUILD: 31: scripts/genksyms/genksyms: not found
cc: error: nvidia/nv_uvm_interface.c: No such file or directory
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
./BUILD: 138: scripts/genksyms/genksyms: not found
cc: error: nvidia-modeset/nvidia-modeset-linux.c: No such file or directory
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

After the upgrade, if I boot into Kernel 5.8.0-45, I get a low resolution display. I can still boot perfectly fine in the previous Kernels. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not using that card, but my own kernel is now at 5.8.9.05089.  So you might see if the next kernel upgrade fixes the issue.

Comment: Same problem here. However, I do notice that the files /usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-45-generic/scripts/genksyms/genksyms and /usr/src/nvidia-460.39/nvidia/nv-frontend.c are present in my system, so it might be a configuration issue rather than a dependency issue.

Comment: @John They’ve pushed an update to linux-image-nvidia that fixed the problem.